# Access to postgresql server from Spring application

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, c3p0

I have a Spring application (Hibernate c3p0) that connects well to an Oracle DB server.
I want to do the same thing with a PostgreSQL DB server, but it sends me the error java.net.UnknownHostException.

In applicationContext, my dataSource is :

```
<bean id="appDS" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://THE_SERVER:5432/schema" />
        <property name="user" value="appc0" />
        <property name="password" value="THE_PWD"  />
</bean>
```

I tried a connection from another very simple java application (from the same server):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        System.out.println("TEST Driver Manager START");
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://THE_SERVER:5432/schema";
        String user = "appc0";
        String passwd = "THE_PWD";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

        System.out.println("Schema : " + conn.getSchema());
        System.out.println("ClientInfo : " + conn.getClientInfo());
        System.out.println("TEST Driver Manager END");

        System.out.println("TEST C3P0 START");
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass( "org.postgresql.Driver" );           
        cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:postgresql://THE_SERVER:5432/schema" );
        cpds.setUser("appc0");                                  
        cpds.setPassword("THE_PWD");                                  

        System.out.println("User :"+ cpds.getUser());
        System.out.println("TEST C3P0 END");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And no mistake in this case, I connect well. This does not seem to be a network problem.
Does anyone know where the problem may come from?

Versions are:

- postgresql-42.2.0.jre7.jar
- c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar

Comment: "*java.net.UnknownHostException.*" is _clearly_  a network problem. Apparently the server where your Tomcat is running can't resolve `THE_SERVER` to a computer in the network. Try the IP address instead

Comment: With the IP, I have the same error. java.net.UnknownHostException : THE_IP. And why does the connection work in my little test application if it's a network problem?

Comment: From the server or computer where the application is running can you `ping THE_SERVER` from the command line?

Comment: Yes : [www@JAVA_SERVER ~ ]$ ping POSTGRE_SERVER PING POSTGRE_SERVER (10.XX.XXX.XXX) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from POSTGRE_SERVER (10.XX.XXX.XXX): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms - 6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5813ms –

Comment: `nslookup THE_SERVER
Server:         10.XX.XX.10
Address:        10.XX.XX.10#53

** server can't find THE_SERVER: NXDOMAIN ` --- `host THE_SERVER
Host THE_SERVER not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. However, simple java application does not return an error. Do you understand something?